# How to add string to a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I'm not sure it's even the right way to define this question.

I have string that may be exist, and may not. It happens to be a number: `$number`

If `$number` doesn't exist, then I want to use the PHP variable `$url`.
But if `$number` does exist, then I want to use the PHP variable which is named `$url+the number`, i.e, `$url2` if `$number=2`

So I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$number = "2"; //(Can be either missing, or equal to 1, 2, or 3)

$url = "www.0.com"; // Fallback
$url1 = "www.1.com";
$url2 = "www.2.com";
$url3 = "www.3.com";

$result = $url.=$number ;

// If $number=1, I want $result to be : www.1.com
// If $number=2, I want $result to be : www.2.com
// If $number=3, I want $result to be : www.3.com
// If $number IS NOT SET, I want $result to be : www.0.com

// Now do something with $result
```

Perhaps there's a completely better way to achieve what I want (will be happy to see example), but anyway I'm curious as well to understand how to achieve it my way.

Comment: Don't be hard on me guys, I'm not a Programmer, just trying to do something on my own

Comment: The best way to do this is to use an array. `$urls = ['www.0.com', 'www.1.com', 'www.2.com', 'www.3.com'];`. Then check if `$urls[intval($number)]` exists and use it, or just use `$url`.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I edited my code to provide example for what I expect

Comment: @DaveChen I get syntax error for `$urls = ['www.0.com', 'www.1.com', 'www.2.com', 'www.3.com'];`

Comment: That's for later versions of PHP, `$urls = array('www.0.com', 'www.1.com');` will work.

Comment: All the answers will suggest using variable variables, but that's just not the spirit of programming. This is the reason there exist arrays.

Comment: I guess @DaveChen didn't check my answer ^_^

Comment: @BenM Heh, I have now. Take my +1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary with `in_array` and `empty`.

```
$number = "2"; //(Can be either missing, or equal to 1, 2, or 3)
$url = "www.0.com"; // Fallback
$url1 = "www.1.com";
$url2 = "www.2.com";
$url3 = "www.3.com";
$result = (!empty($number) && in_array($number, array(1,2,3))) ? ${'url' . $number} : $url;
echo $result;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/821737

Comment: Great, if this resolves your question please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you're talking about a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

You should define the name of the variable you need to use in a string, and then pass that to a variable variable using `$$` syntax:

```
if( isset($number) && is_numeric($number) )
{ 
    $name   = 'url'.$number;
    $result = $$name;
}
else
{
    $result = $url;
}
```

That having been said, you may be better off using an array for this:

```
$urls   = [ 'www.0.com', 'www.1.com', 'www.2.com', 'www.3.com' ];
$result = (!isset($number)) ? $urls[0] : $urls[ intval($number) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `$` front of string, it define variable, so you can use following code:

```
<?php

$number = "2"; //(Can be either missing, or equal to 1/2/3)

$url = "www.0.com"; // Fallback
$url1 = "www.1.com";
$url2 = "www.2.com";
$url3 = "www.3.com";

if(isset($number) && is_numeric($number) && $number <= 3) {
    $variable_name = 'url' . $number; //string like url2
} else {
    $variable_name = 'url';
}

$result = $$variable_name ; //define $url2 from url2 string
echo $result;
// Now do something with $result
```

Example for define variable with string variable:

```
$string = 'hello';
$$string = 'new variable'; //define $hello variable
echo $hello; //Output: "new variable"
```

Comment: Yes I know, please see my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In php you can have things like dynamic variable names:

```
$variableName = "url".$number;
$result = $$variableName;
```

However, you should make sure, that $variableName refers to an existing variable:

```
$result = "www.fallbackURL.com";
if(isset($$variableName)) $result = $$variableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Try this code:

```
  $number = 5;

  $url[0] = "www.0.com"; // Fallback
  $url[1] = "www.1.com";
  $url[2] = "www.2.com";
  $url[3] = "www.3.com";

  if (!isset($number)) $number=0;
  if (!isset($url[$number])) $number=0;

  $result = $url[$number];
```

Answer (score 0):

if the url need just a number, you can do this easy way

```
($number)?$number:0;
$url = "www.".$number.".com";
```

if there are specific real url, you can use array

```
$array[0] = "www.google.com";
$array[1] = "www.facebook.com";
($number)?$number:0;
url = $array[$number];
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated code:

```
$number = "2";

if(isset($number)){
$res = "url".$number;
$result=$$res;
}else{
$result=$url;   
}

echo $result;
```